# Formula for $s_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n i^3$ Newton's Forward Difference Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

> **Use Newton's Forward Difference formula** to find an expression for $$
>  S_n  = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} i^3$$

This is from an Introductory Numerical Analysis paper. I cannot figure out the connection between the expression an Newton interpolation. Any help would be appreciated. Just a hint would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\Delta S_n$? That is, what is $S_{n+1}-S_n$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: $(n + 1)^3$

Comment: Now use the formula: $S_n=S_0+a\Delta S_n+\dfrac{(a)(a-1)}{2}\Delta^2S_n+\dotsb$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: So it doesn't simplify to anything meaningful? (I also found that $\Delta^k S_n = \Delta S_{n + k}$)

Comment: It _does_ simplify. $S_0=0$, $\Delta S_n=n^3+3n^2+3n+1$, $\Delta^2 S_n=3n^2+9n+7$, etc. (if I've done the math right), so just plug those into the formula. In the end, you should be able to write $S_n$ as a polynomial.

Comment: Allright. Thanks a lot.

Comment: but what about the interval h and p?

Comment: h = (n+1) - n ? p = (n - 1(S1 = 1))/1?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger why have you started with $S_0$ and then you use $ \Delta S_n$

Comment: @Upstart It's been seven years. I do not know why I pulled out this random obscure formula and pretended it was well-known, lol. But that is indeed what the formula calls for

Comment: The formula is $y, \Delta y, \Delta^2y$ but index of $y$ does not change in the formula